# Tensorflow Practice Specialization - Input 0 of layer sequential is incompatible with the layer: expected ndim=4, found ndim=5

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, neural-network, conv-neural-network

I am currently doing my TensorFlow specialization assignments, I was working with the horse vs the human dataset ([Download_Dataset](https://storage.googleapis.com/laurencemoroney-blog.appspot.com/horse-or-human.zip)), the idea is to classify if any given image contains a horse or a human. I am following the tutorial ->([Colab tutorial](https://colab.research.google.com/github/lmoroney/dlaicourse/blob/master/Course%201%20-%20Part%208%20-%20Lesson%202%20-%20Notebook.ipynb#scrollTo=RXZT2UsyIVe_)). But I am doing it in my Pycharm IDE.

```
import os
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.image as mpimg
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import RMSprop
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from keras_preprocessing import image
import numpy as np
#--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#                    Pre-Processing and Vizualizing Dataset
#--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Training horse pictures
train_horse_dir = os.path.join('../Dataset/horse_human/horses')
print(train_horse_dir)

#Training human pictures
train_human_dir = os.path.join('../Dataset/horse_human/humans')
print(train_human_dir)

train_horse_names = os.listdir(train_horse_dir)
print(train_horse_names[:10])

train_human_names = os.listdir(train_human_dir)
print(train_human_names[:10])

#number of images in the directory
horse_dir_size = len(os.listdir(train_horse_dir))
human_dir_size = len(os.listdir(train_human_dir))

print("Total training horse images : ", horse_dir_size)
print("Total training human images : ", human_dir_size)


# Pre data vizualization

nrows = 4
ncols = 4
pic_index = 0
knot=10
fig = plt.gcf()
fig.set_size_inches(nrows * 4, ncols * 4)

pic_index = pic_index + 8 + knot

x = train_horse_names[pic_index-8:pic_index]
print("X : ", x)

next_horse_pix = [os.path.join(train_horse_dir,fname)
                  for fname in train_horse_names[pic_index-8:pic_index]]
print("next_horse_pix : ", next_horse_pix)

next_human_pix = [os.path.join(train_human_dir,fname)
                  for fname in train_human_names[pic_index-8:pic_index]]
print("next_human_pix : ", next_human_pix)

for i, img_path in enumerate(next_horse_pix+next_human_pix):
    print(i, img_path)
    sp = plt.subplot(nrows, ncols, i + 1)
    sp.axis('off')
    img = mpimg.imread(img_path)
    plt.imshow(img)

plt.show()

#--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#               Deep Convolution Neural Network
#--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
    #Input shape is 300x300x3(3 bytes color)
    #First convolution
    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(16, (3,3), activation = 'relu', input_shape=(300, 300, 3)),
    tf.keras.layers.MaxPool2D(2, 2),
    # The Second Convolution
    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(32, (3,3), activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.MaxPool2D(2,2),
    # The Third Convolution
    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(64, (3,3), activation = 'relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.MaxPool2D(2,2),
    # The fourth Convolution
    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(64, (3,3), activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.MaxPool2D(2,2),
    # The Fifth Convolution
    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(64, (3,3), activation = 'relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.MaxPool2D(2,2),
    # Flattern the results to feed into a DNN
    tf.keras.layers.Flatten(),
    #512 neuron hidden layer
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(512, activation='relu'),
    #Only 1 output neuron. It will contain a value 0(horse) or 1(humans)
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')
])

model.summary()

model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',
              optimizer = RMSprop(lr=0.001),
              metrics=['accuracy'])

# Rescaling original image to 0 to 1
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1/255)

# Flow training images in batches of 128 using train_datagen generator

train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    '../Dataset/horse_human/', # source directory of the training images
    target_size=(300, 300), # All images will be resized to 150x150
    batch_size=128,
    #since we use binary_crossentropy loss, we need binary labels
    class_mode='binary'
)

history = model.fit(train_generator, steps_per_epoch=8, epochs=15, verbose=1)

img = image.load_img('../Dataset/test_image/4.png', target_size=(300, 300))
print(img)
x = image.img_to_array(img)
x = np.expand_dims(x, axis=0)
images = np.stack([x])
print(images)

classes = model.predict(images, batch_size=10)
print(classes[0])
if classes[0]>0.5:
    print("it is a human")
else:
    print("Its a horse")
```

**Sidenote:**
The test image, that i.e., '../Dataset/test_image/4.png', is a random RGB image of a horse taken from the web. It could literally be any RGB image.

**I get the following error:**

```
ValueError: Input 0 of layer sequential is incompatible with the layer: expected ndim=4, found ndim=5. Full shape received: [None, 1, 300, 300, 3]
```

Please  let me know what change I need to do in the code to over come the error.

Comment: I could not find `../Dataset/test_image/4.png` in dataset

Comment: @ShivamBharadwaj -> '../Dataset/test_image/4.png' could be any random image from the web. It's just for prediction. It could literally be any RGB image of any scale.

Comment: The error is pretty clear, your input has one dimension to many. Why to you `expand_dims` _and_ `stack`?

Comment: @xdurch0 After np.expand_dims(x, axis=0), my x.shape = (1, 300, 300, 3). I am following this tutorial -> https://colab.research.google.com/github/lmoroney/dlaicourse/blob/master/Course%201%20-%20Part%208%20-%20Lesson%202%20-%20Notebook.ipynb#scrollTo=RXZT2UsyIVe_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please look at the `load_img` function [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/preprocessing/image/load_img).

The `load_img` function defaults to load the image in `'rgb'` mode, which itself is 3-channel. You are then expanding the dimension of the loaded image with `axis=0`.

Specifically, the `load_img` returns an image of size (300, 300, 3). Expand the dimensions with `axis=0` results in an array of size (1, 300, 300, 3). Hence you are getting an error. You can remove the following lines and try:

```py
x = np.expand_dims(x, axis=0)
images = np.stack([x])
```